# How do I prove an implication where the consequent does not occur in the premises

Tags: logic

1. (Q→P)→R
2. ∼Q∨S
3. ∼S

∴ ∼R→T

So far I got upto

1. Show ∼R→T
2. ~R                          Assume Conditional Derivation

3~5 Listing premises

6. Show T
7. ~T                          Assume Indirect Derivation
8. ~(Q→P)                      2 3 MT
9. ~Q                          4 5 MTP

Now, I'm not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: This looks like one of those vacuous proofs, as the result involves making a statement about T, which has not appeared so far in any of the axioms.  To construct such a vacuous proof, try to construct a contradictory statement, such as X AND ~X, then build from there.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to show contradictory statement from just the premises, but I don't see the obvious way.

Comment: Ahh, I mised a piece, partial answer incomming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go a bit backwards, because we know what we want to arrive at, so it makes sense to work all of the rules backwards to what we'd like to be true.  Then, at some point, we'll figure out that it actually IS true.  Then we can start from the axioms, and work our way forward to the solution.

One of the rules of propositional logic is that "X->Y" is true for any Y if X is false.  Thus, if you wish to prove ~R->T, when you know nothing about T, one easy solution is to prove that ~R is false, i.e. R is true.

Now, you have one axiom about R's truthfulness, (Q->P)->R.  (Q->P) is the same as (NOT(Q) OR P).  We don't know much about P yet, but we do have some statements about Q.  If we can prove that Q is false, the NOT(Q) must be true, so (NOT(Q) OR P) must be true, which implies R must be true (like we want it to be).

The remaining steps of proving ~Q I leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are using classical logic and => is material implication:

1. (Q => P) => R
2. ¬Q ∨ S
3. ¬S
4. ¬Q ...................2,3 DS
5. ¬Q ∨ P ............4 DI
6. Q => P ............ 5 MIR
7. R ..................... 6,1 MP
8. ¬R  ................... Assumption
9. ¬R ∨ T ................ 8 DI
10. T  ......................... 9,7 DS
11. ¬R => T ............ 10,8 discharging the assumption.